# How do I prove $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to -∞} (x\cdot e^x)=0$ using L'Hôpital's Rule?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital, indeterminate-forms

The above limit can be written as: $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to -∞} (x\cdot e^x)=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to -∞} \frac{e^x}{1/x} $.

The limit is an ***Indeterminate type of ${0/0}$.*** It can be solved using **[L'Hôpital's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule):**

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to -∞} \frac{e^x}{1/x} = \lim_{x\to -∞} \frac{\frac{d}{dx}\left[e^x\right]}{\frac{d}{dx}\left[1/x\right]} = \lim_{x\to -∞} \frac{e^x}{-1/x^2}$

Here the *numerator* ${e^x\to 0}$ and *denominator* ${-1/x^2\to 0}$ as ${x\to -∞}$. So after using **[L'Hôpital's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule)** the limit is still an ***Indeterminate type of ${0/0}$.*** How do I find a limit that's not an ***Indeterminate type***?

Answer (score 2):

Let $y=-x\to \infty$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}xe^{x}=\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}-ye^{-y}=\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}-\frac{y}{e^{y}}\stackrel{H.R.}{=}\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}-\frac{1}{e^{y}}$$

As an alternative since eventually $e^y\ge y^2$ by squeeze theorem

$$0\le \frac{y}{e^{y}}\le \frac{y}{y^2}=\frac1y \to0$$

Comment: You didn't use _L'Hôpital's Rule_.

Comment: He did use it on the first line

Comment: Yes I did and I gave also a standard alternative be squeeze theorem.

Comment: I always suggest in these cases to change variable in order to deal with limit $\to +\infty$ which are simpler to handle.

Comment: Ok. I understand it now. Thanks for the alternative with squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try $\frac{x}{1/e^x}$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

Flipping over get
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}xe^{x}&=\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\dfrac{x}{e^{-x}}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\dfrac{1}{-e^{-x}}\\
&=0.
\end{align*}